# Use mini gmap extracts for steps on a track

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a particular question and I don't even find how to explain it :
I have a google maps with a track and X steps on it.
I want to add a "mini" map extract in front of each waypoint to make it more readable.

[image]
I think the only way is to recreate X new maps, each one with the track on it and the concerned waypoint, but I'm not absolutely sure about it.

Do you think there is a way to use just a part of the main map, like in the example? Main idea is to prevent page from loading 8 different maps, each one with the track, because I'm asuming this could be a bit hard to load.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You do need to create new maps one for each step, each one with the track on it and the concerned waypoint, you don't need to rerun the directions query though.  What does your existing code look like?

Comment: Track is displayed from a GPX file.
Waypoints comes from wpt and trace from trk->trkseg, so it's not really easy tu cut only a little part of the track. If i have to make 1 map for each waypoint, i think i have no other choice than redisplaying the whole track.